# Merging 2 csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge 2 csv files. Resulting data frame column should have all the columns from csv 1.
For ex:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer')`

Result df3:
name value
foo   1
bar   2
baz   3
foo   5 
NaN   6 
NaN   7 
NaN   8

How can i get the above result using joins?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Please provide input, expected output and the code you have tried so far.

Comment: i want to merge 2 csv files. For ex csv 1 has 10 columns 50 rows and csv 2 has 12 columns 10 rows . But both columns are not exactly same . only few columns are common between them. After merging , I want the result dataframe which will have all 10 columns ( from csv 1 ) and 60 rows (50+10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you sorted,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer')
df3.drop([item for item in df2.columns if item not in df1.columns],axis = 1)
```

Which gives

[image: This]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(result)
```